# Html.RenderPartial in Asp.Net Mvc 4 doesn't work fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, http-post, asp.net-mvc-partialview, modalpopup

I have view that display **Companies' CardView**.Every card has add new **BankAccount** button to display "Add new bank account" modal popup. My view as follow:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Companies.Count(); i += 3)
{
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="box corner-all">
            <div class="box-header grd-white">
                <div class="header-control">
                    <div>

                        <ul class="breadcrumb-nav pull-right">
                            <li class="btn-group">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <i class="icofont-cogs"></i>Controls
                                    <i class="icofont-caret-down"></i>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#MyCreate" role="button" class="" data-toggle="modal">Add new bankaccount</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#collapse" data-toggle="tab">@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", Model.Companies.ElementAt(i), new { target = "_blank" })</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        @{Html.RenderPartial("BankCreateModal", new BankAccountCreateViewModel { BankAccount = new Invoice.Model.BankAccount(), TaxTypes = Model.TaxTypes, CompanyID = Model.Companies.ElementAt(i).ID });}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span>@Model.Companies.ElementAt(i).ShortName</span>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            <div class="resume-photo">
                                <img src="~/Content/img/LogoFiles/@Model.Companies.ElementAt(i).LogoFile" style="width: 50px; height: 45px;"/>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                        <td>@Model.Companies.ElementAt(i).FullName</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    @*<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>*@
                    <strong></strong>@Model.Companies.ElementAt(i).CompanyDescription
                </div>

            </div>
            <div style="text-align: center; padding-left: 22px;">
                <div class="thumbnails pricing-table color-black">
                    <div class="span3 active grd-white box-shadow" style="width: 270px;">
                        <div class="bank_details_expand">
                            <div class="features">
                                <div id="slideshow-area">
                                    <div id="slideshow-previous"></div>
                                    <div id="slideshow-next"></div>
                                    <div id="slideshow-scroller">
                                        <div id="slideshow-holder">
                                            @foreach (var bank in Model.BankAccounts.ElementAt(i))
                                            {
                                                <div class="slideshow-content">
                                                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                                                        <!--box body-->
                                                        <div class="box-body">
                                                            <!-- Button to trigger modal -->

                                                            <!-- Modal -->

                                                            @{Html.RenderPartial("BankEditModal", new BankAccountEditViewModel { BankAccount = bank, TaxTypes = Model.TaxTypes });}

                                                        </div>
                                                        <!--/box body-->
                                                        <ul style="text-align: left;">
                                                            <li></li>
                                                            <li><span style="font-weight: bolder; color: #0B72E0">Bank Name:</span>
                                                                <span style="font-style: italic;">@bank.BankName</span></li>
                                                            <li><span style="font-weight: bolder; color: #0B72E0">Corr. Account:</span>
                                                                <span style="font-style: italic;">@bank.CorrespondentAccount</span> </li>
                                                            <li><span style="font-weight: bolder; color: #0B72E0">IBAN:</span>
                                                                <span style="font-style: italic;">@bank.IBAN </span></li>
                                                            <li><span style="font-weight: bolder; color: #0B72E0">Code:</span>
                                                                <span style="font-style: italic;">@bank.Code</span></li>
                                                            <li><span style="font-weight: bolder; color: #0B72E0">SWIFT:</span>
                                                                <span style="font-style: italic;">@bank.SWIFT</span></li>
                                                            <li><span style="font-weight: bolder; color: #0B72E0">Tax Type:</span>
                                                                <span style="font-style: italic;">@bank.Tax.Presentage % </span></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            }

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bank-details-control">
                            <div class="footer grd-white" data-box="expandBank">
                                <div>Bank Details</div>
                                <i class="icofont-chevron-down"></i>
                                @*<a class="btn btn-block  btn-warning" data-box="expandBank">Bank Details</a>*@
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (Model.Companies.Count() - 1 > i)
    {

     @{Html.RenderPartial("BankCreateModal", new BankAccountCreateViewModel {       BankAccount = new Invoice.Model.BankAccount(), TaxTypes = Model.TaxTypes, CompanyID =     Model.Companies.ElementAt(i + 1).ID });}
      }
    @if (Model.Companies.Count() - 2 > i)
    {

       @{Html.RenderPartial("BankCreateModal", new BankAccountCreateViewModel { BankAccount = new Invoice.Model.BankAccount(), TaxTypes = Model.TaxTypes, CompanyID = Model.Companies.ElementAt(i + 2).ID });}
    }

}
```

PartialView for create bankaccount as follow

```
@model InvoiceModel.HelperClasses.BankAccountCreateViewModel

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<div id="MyCreate" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-       labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h2 id="myModalLabel">Bank Account</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateModal", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Createmodal", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TaxTypes)
        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BankAccount.BankName)

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BankAccount.BankName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankAccount.BankName)
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BankAccount.CorrespondentAccount)

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BankAccount.CorrespondentAccount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankAccount.CorrespondentAccount)
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BankAccount.IBAN)

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BankAccount.IBAN)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankAccount.IBAN)
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BankAccount.Code)

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BankAccount.Code)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankAccount.Code)
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BankAccount.SWIFT)

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BankAccount.SWIFT)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankAccount.SWIFT)
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BankAccount.TaxID, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BankAccount.TaxID, new SelectList(Model.TaxTypes, "ID", "Name"), new { data_placeholder = "Select Tax Type", data_form = "select2" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankAccount.TaxID)
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    }
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
</div>
```

So, When I click **SaveChanges** button I can create new bank for first company, but when click for other company in bankaccountcontroller my CompanyID is the same with first company. My **HTTPPOST** action as follow

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateModal(BankAccountCreateViewModel bank)
    {

        bank.BankAccount.CompanyID = bank.CompanyID;
        bankRepository.SaveBankAccount(bank.BankAccount);

        return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index");
    }
```

How can I fix this problem? I need second or other companyID, not first.

Comment: In your loop, you're rendering several partial views and in all of them you're adding all 3 scripts. Also, all forms have the same id, CreateModal, this is likely to create errors. Take a look at the rendered html and check for errors there.

Comment: Yes, @lopezbertoni. I found this problem myself, and now my popup work fine. Thank you

Comment: No problem, glad your code works now.